# Importing a raw file in a specific way

Tags: excel, vba, parsing, import

I would like to import a raw file that is not plaintext.
The values I'd like to import is a single line of character that I need to import, split into single characters,and convert to Hex values between 00 and FF.
There are 49152 characters and I'd like it to import in 3 columns. A 3 x 16384
like this:

```
01 02 03
04 05 06
```

### ↓this↓ works but doesn't give leading zeros. (1 should be 01). also, It ignores values that do not cover all three columns.↓

Sub Demo()
    Dim fl As String
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim fn As Integer
    Dim rOutput As Range
    Dim idx As Long
    Dim FileLength As Long
    Dim v

```
fn = FreeFile
fl = "C:\Users\1097180551N\Desktop\untitled.png"

Set rOutput = [A1]

Open fl For Binary Access Read As #fn

FileLength = LOF(fn)
ReDim dat(1 To FileLength \ 3, 1 To 3)

For idx = 1 To UBound(dat, 1)
    v = Input(3, #fn)
    dat(idx, 1) = Hex(Asc(Mid$(v, 1, 1)))
    dat(idx, 2) = Hex(Asc(Mid$(v, 2, 1)))
    dat(idx, 3) = Hex(Asc(Mid$(v, 3, 1)))
Next
rOutput.Resize(UBound(dat, 1), 3) = dat
Close #fn
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your last update code is nearly there.  I would read the file as *Binary* rather than *Input*, and convert the characters into printable form.  Also, using a variant array will be faster than writing the the sheet directly

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim fl As String
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim fn As Integer
    Dim rOutput As Range
    Dim idx As Long
    Dim FileLength As Long
    Dim v

    fn = FreeFile
    fl = "C:\Users\1097180551N\Desktop\txt.raw"

    Set rOutput = [A1]

    Open fl For Binary Access Read As #fn

    FileLength = LOF(fn)
    ReDim dat(1 To FileLength \ 3, 1 To 3)

    For idx = 1 To UBound(dat, 1)
        v = Input(3, #fn)
        dat(idx, 1) = Hex(Asc(Mid$(v, 1, 1)))
        dat(idx, 2) = Hex(Asc(Mid$(v, 2, 1)))
        dat(idx, 3) = Hex(Asc(Mid$(v, 3, 1)))
    Next
    rOutput.Resize(UBound(dat, 1), 3) = dat

    Close #fn
End Sub
```

Comment: ++ agreed. I would use some more reasonable names for the variables but that's just a matter of preference I guess. Also the part that populated the `dat()` could be thrown in a small 1-3 loop ;)